# Including file server into domain

Tags: permissions, domain, ntfs, file-server

We have a file server in our LAN. Windows 2003 Server. It was not included into our domain. Every user has local account on that server, and NTFS permissions are granted to those local accounts.

Now we have established a domain controller. Every user has got a domain account. How to include file server into domain so that the permissions would transfer from local accounts to domain accounts? Is it possible to automate this process somehow?

Answer (score 3):

The only way to achieve what you want to do is through scripting. One way is to export the permissions to text file(s) using `srvcheck.exe`. Then, using search and replace, change the details as required. Finally import the new permissions back in using `SetACL.exe`. This kind of thing is not for the feint of heart and has considerable room for error.

Comment: +1 ...but if done properly it would save considerable time doing it all manually, even with having to go back and fix the one-offs.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea; move from NTFS permissions to share-level permissions only and set NTFS to everyone full. Stuff that needs different permissions ... use another share.

My experience is that NTFS permissions are complex, fragile (easy to turn off inheritance, for example) and suffer from the "move/copy" problem ... move a file moves perms, copy inherits perms of destination. Very confusing for users, and security hole.

Comment: It's generally encouraged and arguably best practice to do exactly the opposite of what you suggest.

Comment: Yes, I know. Using NTFS permissions on files/directories makes you more secure ... IF it is done right and maintained. In my company, my observation is that over time, the complexity causes errors that are hard to find, and therefore leads to less security.